# Get current price, pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to figure out how to call current price when a certain condition exists. For example:

```
if ta.crossover(short, long)
    get.price(current) := someInteger

strategy.exit("closePosition", from_entry="long", limit=someInteger)
```

I cant seem to figure out how to set a limit based on some condition, rather than a specific price.

i tried using line.get_price() but i'm not sure if that's what I need or not.

Comment: actually, i just figured it out. i used 
    
    ta.valuewhen(condition, source, occurence)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `var` variable for that.

```
var float limit_price = na

if ta.crossover(short, long)
    limit_price := close
```

Or you can use the `ta.valuewhen()` function.

> Returns the value of the `source` series on the bar where the
> `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.

```
limit_price = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(short, long), close, 0)
```

Comment: I did end up using the ta.valuewhen function for that. i posted the comment under my initial post shortly after i made the OP.

follow up question though: how can I identify some point that doesn't yet exist?  for example, if I wanted to set a stoploss 5 points above the pivot high over the last say 100 sessions...

    stopLoss = ta.valuewhen((ta.highest(100) + 5), high, 0) 

^ that doesn't work